# How's JavaScript prototyping done right?

Tags: javascript

After I've read numerous of posts about JavaScript prototyping, written by people the day after writing their first line of code, I have to ask - does anyone know how to make a proper JavaScript prototype chain? How to prototype this very simple thing (?):

- Continent
- Country
- Region
- City
- Neighbourhood

Then this sample code would work:

```
var södermalm = sweden["södermalm"];
console.info(södermalm.neighbourhood + " is located on the continent " + södermalm.continent);
```

And also this:

```
if (!sweden.neighbourhood) console.warn("Sweden is a country")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Continent(nameOfContinent) {
  this.continent = nameOfContinent;
}
Continent.prototype.getType = function () { return 'Continent'; }

function Country(nameOfCountry, nameOfContinent) {
  Continent.call(this, nameOfContinent);
  this.country = nameOfCountry;
}
Country.prototype = new Continent();
Country.prototype.getType = function () { return 'Country'; }


function Region(nameOfRegion, nameOfCountry, nameOfContinent) {
  Country.call(this, nameOfCountry, nameOfContinent);
  this.region = nameOfRegion;
}
Region.prototype = new Country();
Region.prototype.getType = function () { return 'Region'; }


function City(nameOfCity, nameOfRegion, nameOfCountry, nameOfContinent) {
  Region.call(this, nameOfRegion, nameOfCountry, nameOfContinent);
  this.city = nameOfCity;
}
City.prototype = new Region();
City.prototype.getType = function () { return 'City'; }



function Neighbourhood(nameOfNeighbourhood, nameOfCity, nameOfRegion, nameOfCountry, nameOfContinent) {
  City.call(this, nameOfCity, nameOfRegion, nameOfCountry, nameOfContinent);
  this.neighbourHood = nameOfNeighbourhood;
}
Neighbourhood.prototype = new City();
Neighbourhood.prototype.getType = function () { return 'Neighbourhood'; }


let dehradun = new City('dehradun', 'uttarakhand', 'india', 'asia');
let divyaVihar = new Neighbourhood('divya vihar', 'dehradun', 'uttarakhand', 'india', 'asia');

console.log(divyaVihar);

console.log(divyaVihar.neighbourHood + " is located on the continent " + divyaVihar.continent);

console.log(divyaVihar instanceof Neighbourhood);

if(!(dehradun instanceof Neighbourhood)) {
  console.log(dehradun.getType())
}
```

Comment: The `constructor` of all the prototypes is set to `Continent`?

Comment: Yes, generally the constructor will point to the Continent. We can also rectify this by adding the following lines 'Child.prototype.constructor = Child'